# 3 column layout for a video player page?

Tags: website-design, layout

I'm designing a new layout for a popular video site.

We are doing a "large" layout for min-width 1366px. 
The video player can't get any bigger, so on the video player pages, we have some extra room for the large layouts.
Is it better:

1. To center everything on the page and have about 50px of whitespace
   on the sides. (the header being bigger than the content div)
2. To have a 3rd column on the right with maybe related images from our image
   section as there is already a section for related videos on the
   page. I find the 3rd column fills the space but looks way more
   cluttered.. are there any takes on 3-column layouts with media on
   the page?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbpPlU.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmPMgb.png)</sup>

Comment: Can you atleast add a wireframe or screenshot as an example for greater visualization

Comment: Like mervinj, I think a wireframe or screeny would be very helpful for understanding the possibilities and constraints.

Comment: I added wireframes

Answer (score 1):

The third column is going to add a huge amount of visual noise to the page -- if you want users to see related images I'd provide an easy way to do so, but embedding previews on the page seems like an overload.

Given the large vid size and the large size of content in the second column, I'd go for the calming effect of the white space and centering. Remember, [white space](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/01/12/white-space-and-simplicity-an-overview/) [isn't necessarily dead space](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/whitespace/).

Comment: thank you, this is what I'm trying to explain to my director but he insists on cramming more onto the page.

Comment: You might also review http://www.ojr.org/ojr/stories/070312ruel/ which includes studies by Nielsen. And Tom Roberts has a nice article on white space: http://idratherbewriting.com/2007/07/09/white-space-in-web-design/. Findings generally come out across all these articles the same way - it improves comprehension, is easier on the eye, focuses attention, etc.